# Java concurrency - what is the "cachable" scope

Tags: java, concurrency, scope

I am trying to understand how exactly concurrent programming work in Java. A lot of times I read different things for concurrency and so on. But I am not sure what is the `cachable` scope. With `cachable` I mean from where threads can cache variables.

For example if I have my custom `Thread`:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
private boolean isRunning;

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    isRunning = running;
}
public boolean getRunning(){
    return isRunning;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning){
        // ... do something
    }
}
}
```

So lets assume I have the following `main` method:

```
 public static void Main(String[] args) {

    Person p = new Person();

    final MyThread t1 = new MyThread();
    final MyThread t2 = new MyThread();
    Thread t3 = new Thread(()-> {
        while(true){System.out.println(p.name);
        System.out.println(t1.getRunning());
    }});
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}
```

Lets assume that there is a code after this which can change this objects properties (but not the references to which they point!). And lets point that I am asking about caching, not about concurrency modifying;
So my questions are:
1) Can `t3` see wrong value to `p.name` and `t1.isRunning`. -> I think `No`, because I think it can cache the references to this objects, so if we change the reference to which `p` points `t3`, can see wrong person reference, but in this case it will cache the right reference, so it will go the main memory(RAM) and will get the right value.
2) Can `t2` cache `t2.isRunning` (its own `isRunning` variable)? So should I synchronize usage of `setRunning` and `getRunning`?

So for example if in `t3` I have code like this: `t2.setRunning(false)` can `t2` loop forever (if  only this code in `t3` change `t2.isRunning`)? 
Of course, if `t2` can cache its own variables I should use `volatile` or `synchronize`. I think that `t2` can cache its isRunning.
So how can we understand which is the `cachable` scope in different situations.
Everywhere in my code I access variables of object with their objects (directly or with getters/setters) and I am not saving them as variables somewhere else! 
Sorry, if there is an answer of my questions(or if they are stupid), but I cannot find a direct one - with examples. When I read only theoretically (without any examples and explanation what can get wrong with them) I am not sure whether I imagine the things right. 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: This is not just an issue of the behaviour of the CPU cache as non-volatile fields can be inlined into code and never read again. esp booleans.

Answer (score 1):

In general Java can cache variables until it reaches either `synchronized` block/method or accesses `volatile` variable. After any of those it has to invoke memory barrier and re-read content of all cached variables.

The above includes also any code which is called by the higher function, so in your case for examples `System.out.println()` triggers this sync action, therefore the `t3` will see always up to date content of `p`.

For `MyThread.run` it depends whether "do something" contains any kind of synchronization above. If yes then Java will not be allowed to cache isRunning, if no it may run forever (still depends on JIT optimizations etc).

One more note about `p = Person()` - this is final anyway, therefore the first question is irrelevant, you can't change the `p` variable anytime in future, just the content which is already answered in paragraph two.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a definitive answer because your code in running in a virtual machine and there is no defined way it will be turned into real code.  The only guarantees are those you find in the JLS regarding memory barriers.  As such it doesn't have anything to say about caches, nor even whether your CPU has to have one.

> 1) Can t3 see wrong value to p.name and t1.isRunning.

It will see the correct value because they were set when the thread started. If they were changed later, you might never see that change.

> so if we change the reference to which p points t3, can see wrong person reference,

A captured value cannot change. This is not a threading issue.

> so it will go the main memory(RAM) and will get the right value.

Usually it doesn't go to main memory, whether you do a thread safe read or not. It only goes to main memory if there is no copy of the data on the CPU socket. In some architectures it can even copy the data from another Socket without going to main memory.

> 2) Can t2 cache t2.isRunning (its own isRunning variable)?

Not only can it cache it but it can inline it so it never reads the value again.

> So should I synchronize usage of setRunning and getRunning?

You could do but making the field `volatile` would be an order of magnitude cheaper (or more)

> So for example if in t3 I have code like this: t2.setRunning(false) can t2 loop forever (if only this code in t3 change t2.isRunning)?

As it is, yes it can.  if you make it volatile, it won't.

> Of course, if t2 can cache its own variables I should use volatile or synchronize. I think that t2 can cache its isRunning. So how can we understand which is the cachable scope in different situations.

You are not supposed to write code which depends too heavily on how the CPU caches are implemented.  You should think in terms of thread safe access and memory barriers as these are defined in the JLS (Java Language Specification) so you can reason about these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I shouldn't write code that depends on CPU caches. But why is this: `If they were changed later, you might never see that change.` in your post. This is about `Can t3 see wrong value to p.name and t1.isRunning.`. Does t3 caches the whole object (in case which it caches) or? Before your answer I imagine that a reference can be cached, not the whole object.
Thanks for your attention.